# opengl textures are not displayed, though code is almost identical to a code example

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I have a serious problem with OpenGL ES 1.1 and I can't find the solution though I've looked over it like a thousand times, and I haven't found anything like a comparable problem here. I hope you guys can help me.

I watched tutorial 2 at 71squared.com (you can find it [here](http://www.71squared.com/2009/03/iphone-game-programming-tutorial-2-image-class/)) and downloaded the code example from the same page. It runs fine.

Then I tried to write my own code in order to adapt it to my project. Anyway, when it comes to OpenGL calls, I paid attention to using the same code as the example.

The problem is the following: my call to glClear() affects the color of the screen, though my textures are not displayed. The problem can be caused neither by the UIView subclass (as glClear() is displayed), nor by the code loading the textures, as all iVars of the corresponding instances are calculated correctly. In addition, even the texture coordinates and the vertices take normal values, which are the same as in the code example. So the problem must be caused by some tiny mistake I made using OpenGL.

These are all of my OpenGL calls:

Initializing:

```
CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

        // Set up OpenGL projection matrix
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrthof(0, rect.size.width, 0, rect.size.height, -1, 1);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glViewport(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);

        // Initialize OpenGL states
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_BLEND_SRC);
        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

Drawing the Texture:

(t is a pointer to a struct containing information about how to draw the graphic.)

```
glPushMatrix();

glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glTranslatef(t->posX, t->posY, 0.0f);
glRotatef(-(t->rotation), 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glColor4f(t->filter[0], t->filter[1], t->filter[2], t->filter[3]);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _texture.name);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, _texCoords);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

glDisable(GL_BLEND);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

glPopMatrix();
```

I think this is where the problem is caused. If you want to see my code creating a frame buffer, I can show it to you. It is, again, nearly the same as in the example, though.

I'm quite desperate finding the solution, as I have single stepped through the whole code like a thousand times, but I can't find the piece of code where I do something different than the code example.

Thank you in advance.
Dominik

Answer (score 0):

Each time you generate a texture image, you have to check this texture is valid by this method.
If this texture is not valid, you need to re-generate it with some delay time.

```
GLboolean glIsTexture(GLuint texture);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, @Toro. I didn't know that. I've just tested it, though, and it seems that this is not causing the problems. Thank you anyway.